# Active Thread Number in Thread Pool

Tags: c#, threadpool

When I write the below code, why do I get avaliable Thread number like 1022, 1020.
I have to get 25 thread max as I am using thread pool.

I guess the ouput thread number is the avaliable threads on the system. I need to get the avaliable thread number in my thread pool, in win form application.

```
private void Foo()
{
    int intAvailableThreads, intAvailableIoAsynThreds;

    // ask the number of avaialbe threads on the pool,
    //we really only care about the first parameter.
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out intAvailableThreads,
        out intAvailableIoAsynThreds);

    // build a message to log
    string strMessage =
        String.Format(@"Is Thread Pool: {1},
            Thread Id: {2} Free Threads {3}",
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread.ToString(),
            Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode(),
            intAvailableThreads);

    // check if the thread is on the thread pool.
    Trace.WriteLine(strMessage);

    // create a delay...
    Thread.Sleep(30000);

    return;
}
```

Thanks alot..

(Note : I got the code from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AsyncMethodInvocation.aspx)
Nice article!!

Comment: No doubt that article is excellent, but it is written in 2006 !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I have to get 25 thread max as I am using thread pool.

The maximum number of threads in the thread-pool per core has changed a lot over time. It's no longer 25 per core, which I suspect is what you were expecting.

For example, running this on my quad-core hyperthreaded laptop with .NET 4, I get a maximum of 32767 worker threads and 1000 IO completion port threads:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int worker; 
        int ioCompletion;
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out worker, out ioCompletion);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} / {1}", worker, ioCompletion);
    }    
}
```

Under .NET 3.5 I get 2000 worker threads and still 1000 IO completion port threads.

That isn't the number of threads actually in the thread pool though - it's the maximum number that the thread pool allows itself to create over time.

Comment: I set Thread.SetMaxThread to 10001, after that whenever, I run your program it shows max thread 10001, its persisted. I didn't restarted my core i 5 system. is it possible on your system some process set it to the numbers you given?

Comment: I wonder how you got 2000 worker threads in fw 3.5 , while it suppose to be 250 per core ( in fw3.5) - so quad=4 which means 4*250 = 1000. ( so it's pretty odd that you got 2000).....(mmm maybe the hyperthreaded thingy ?)

Comment: These numbers have nothing to do with the number of threads actually in use in the thread pool. What is everyone talking about here?  Thread pool is not going to start by creating 250 threads.

Comment: @Triynko: I agree, it's about the *maximum* number of threads - I'll clarify.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads.aspx) to get what you want.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx) helps explain everything you need to know about `ThreadPool`.

Comment: It seems you can lead a horse to water but sometimes you're supposed to copy and paste it for them too...

Comment: @Rory, or, it seems like this answer is just a link, and should be a comment instead.

Answer (score 1):

I set both to 10001, using ThreadPool.SetMaxThread. After that whenever, I run your program it shows max thread 10001, its persisted. I didn't restarted my core i 5 system.

After that I set both it to 10000000 , and it is showing following thread max count

worker:32767 ioCompletion:32767

So on my Windows 7 Intel Core i5 , this is the maximum capacity.

Answer (score -1):

```
int available;
int maxLimit;
System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out available, out maxLimit);
```

Comment: In this function the available is the available threads, but maxLimit is the available completion ports. You need to call GetMaxThreads to find out maxLimit.