# Thread pool extreme perfomance lag

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, threadpool

There have been quite a few discussions on the issue, but they can't seem to explain my particular problem. **I'm having serious performence issues when threading useing ThreadPool instead of Thread class.**

The details:

I have built a tcp server, when the tcp server accepts a new client it spawns a new thread to handle that client. All Fairly simple, but it takes my server way too long to handle many concurrent clients. 30 seconds for about 35 simple clients that just send a 2048 byte buffer, recieve it and close.

After many stopwathes I found that `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` takes up to 26 seconds. I use it to spawn new threads for handling new clients.
After replacing `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` with `new Thread()` my performance improved to less then a second.

I would love some explanation to why this is happening.

**Clarification:**

The Delay has nothing to do with the client code, from the moment ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is called until clientMsgHandler.HandleIncomingMsgs is started 20 seconds can pass.

The lag starts at very first threads, and actually improves slightly as the test continues. I'm less interested in solutions and more interested in an explanation to why it's happening. 
The client does block, but for a very short while.

The server code:

```
private void AddTcpClientMsgHandler(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        //lock so no addition of client and closure can occur concurrently
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        Monitor.Enter(this);
        int pWatchIdx =  watchIDX++;
        if (!isOpen)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(ResourceAlreadyClosed);

        TcpClientMsgHandler clientMsgHandler = CreateClientHandler(tcpClient);                                         
        clientMsgHandlerManager.AddTcpClientMsgHandler(clientMsgHandler);
        //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(clientMsgHandler.HandleIncomingMsgs); takes 20 seconds to run
        Thread thread = new Thread(clientMsgHandler.HandleIncomingMsgs);
        thread.Start();
        watch.Stop();
        Monitor.Exit(this);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Iteration {0} took {1} Client {2}", pWatchIdx.ToString(),watch.Elapsed, tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint));

    }
```

Comment: Try using a performance profiler like [Red Gate's ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

Comment: Are you perhaps running out of threads on the threadpool?

Comment: The generic diagnostic is that your HandleIncomingMsgs() method is taking way too long.  Not using Monitor.Exit() in a finally block is serious bug btw.

Comment: Why don't you use TPL's Task.Factory.StartNew method with a custom TaskScheduler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781658(v=vs.100).aspx) that has a set concurrency level?

Comment: Rudi, no I'm using a powerful computer and am opening less then a 100 threads. 
Hans, it isn't taking long, in fact it takes less then a millisecond. But thanks for the remark about the finally I'll do that just in case.
Max, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blocking code is the enemy of the ThreadPool. From the example you posted, it's not possible to tell where the blocking is happening, but I suggest that you review the code path to find out where the code is blocking. Run your server in the debugger until it starts showing high latency then break execution and take a look in the threads panel of VS. This will show you where the threads have blocked. Most likely this is on synchronous IO. Consider replacing with asynchronous code.

Comment: You're probably right. I tried that and blocking threads cause massive latency when run in the ThreadPool. Can you explain it perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem -  Queues a method for execution. The method executes when a thread pool thread becomes available.

- The ThreadPool waits for an idle thread.
- When an idle thread is found the ThreadPool uses it to execute your method.

Why ThreadPool is slow ?

- The above two is not really a reason until you are running out of Threads in ThreadPool.
- Under .NET 3.5 there are 2000 worker threads and 1000 IO completion port threads. (even more in 4.0,4.5) . Check [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236493/active-thread-number-in-thread-pool) answer (Active Thread Number in Thread Pool).

[For eg.]

.Net 2.0 defaults to 25 threads per available processor. This means that if you queue up 30 tasks, the last five will have to wait for threads to become available from the pool before being executed.

Solution :

**SetMinThreads()** to make the minimum number of threads 30 (for .Net 2.0).
This will increase performance since the ThreadPool won’t immediately create new threads when needed; it only does this on certain intervals.

Note : Using one thread per Client doesn't support more concurrency.

Use **Asynchronous sockets** - These are non-blocking sockets, except that you don’t have to poll: the stack sends the program a special window message whenever something "interesting" happens.

Comment: My process had at most 50 threads on a quad core cpu, doesn't add up.

Comment: Obviously, no chance for thread scarcity :) You may look into Which I/O Strategy Should be Used? Blocking or Non-Blocking I/O (what is your HandleIncomingMsgs)

Answer (score 0):

After the first few threads in the threadpool are used up, the system introduces a delay before starting each new threadpool thread (this doesn't affect re-used threads).

You can change the initial number of threadpool threads by setting [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx) to a suitably large value before you start any threads. BUT YOU ARE NOT SUPPOSED TO DO THAT! (So you didn't hear that from me... ;)

You should look into a way of reducing the number of threads instead of doing that.

Comment: Boom. Your server just exploded.

Comment: Close. Last I heard it was a 0.5 second delay and in a Server app you could fiddle wit MinThreads ( a little)

Comment: Exactly. The correct approach is to change the implementation so that it doesn't use so many threads. The scope of that answer is beyond the time I have to reply just now!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's depending about what you are doing in your `clientMsgHandler.HandleIncomingMsgs()` method.
The thread pool must be use only for really short treatments.

Furthermore, the thread pool has a default size of 25 worker threads per available processor, be careful of crosslock in your thread.

[>> The Managed Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx)